# How do I scroll down a page with <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I am making a page on my website that is kind of like a mini wiki. By that I mean I am having a page of information. At the top, I want a table of contents, where you click a link and it scrolls down. I think this would be html, but it might be css.

I used to know how to do this, but I can't remember, nor can I seem to find how to do it anywhere.

So to sum the question up, I want to use an `<a>` tag in html to, when clicked, scroll to a spot on the page.

Comment: Where's your code showing us what you've tried?

Comment: You can use an anchor. [Here](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) is a good reference on this.

Comment: Thanks Eli, helps alot!

Comment: Duplicate of [URL “fragment identifier” semantics for HTML documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985569/url-fragment-identifier-semantics-for-html-documents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you give your content title `h1` or similar an `id` that matches the `#` request, it will scroll to that content - whether it's on the same page or a different page. Basic example below

Link:

```
<a href="#sectiontitle">Section Title</a>
```

Content:

```
<h1 id="sectiontitle">Section Title Content</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks! helped a lot. I figured it would be something like that, just couldn't get it to work.

Comment: No problem at all

Comment: @Ampck would you be able to mark this answer as accepted/correct? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anchor for that. Prepend the `href` by a `#`, and it will scroll to an element on the page with the same `id` value as what you put after the `#`.

For example :

```
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

... will link you to this :

```
<h1 id="contact">Contact us</h1>
```

... in the same page.